# CSS for same level

Tags: css, css-selectors

If I have 3 divs at the same level ( not one in another ) . How can I change the color of the other div when hover one without using IDs and classes. I would like somthing like :

```
<div id="1" ></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

And CSS :

```
#1 :hover < body > div
{
    //Here I change the things
}
```

Comment: I think you'll need javascript also

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use the general sibling combinator

```
#yourId:hover ~ div
{
    color:red;
}
```

Also note that Id's must begin with a letter. [W3 ID Attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2)

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/rNKzG/)

Comment: And if I want that the divs that are before change too ?

Comment: As mentioned in my comment to your newer question, it's not possible.

Comment: @user1365010 In that case you'd have to go with Petah's answer, there isn't yet a css parent selector.

Comment: This will work only for the divs AFTER the hovered one. Not the siblings on the same level

Answer (score 3):

Put a wrapper around them, then put the hover on the wrapper.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="element">foo</div>
    <div class="element">bar</div>
    <div class="element">baz</div>
</div>

.wrapper:hover .element {
    color: red;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/EB92r/

Comment: This will change the color of the hovered element as well. This is not the answer!

Comment: @Janusz'Ivellios'Kamieński that really depends on your use case, if you want them to be different colors do this: http://jsfiddle.net/4un13ftq/

Comment: That's true. It depends on the case, but the question was about elements selected on the same level. I have a case with an element which is second in the line and I want to show the element above and below ONLY on hover on this particular element. This cannot be done with `~` selector as it will only look forward in the DOM. Your solution will work on all "other" hovered elements as well. But it may be a good starting point. A little hacky, but could work if "disable" the changes on hover on the first and the last element.