# highlight the same level nodes when hover in CSS

Tags: css

I have a similar tree structure to below. As you see, when hover on 2 then 3 and 4 will be highlighted. I want the 0 and 1 will be highlighted when hover on 2 but not the other way around. Is it possible to do this just by CSS?

```
<style>
    li {
        padding: 3px;
        list-style: none;
        text-align: center;
        border: 1px solid black;
        display: table;
    }

    li:hover , li:hover + ul li  {
        background-color: goldenrod;
    }

</style>

<div>
    <ul>
        <li>0</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <ul>
            <ul>
                <li>3
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            4
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>5</li>
        <li>6</li>
        <ul>
            <ul>
                <li>7
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            8
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Your HTML structure is invalid. The Sub-menus should be INSIDE the li

Comment: A UL cannot be a direct child of another Ul

Comment: It called "Sibling combinator". https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10442336/css-for-same-level

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS for same level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10442336/css-for-same-level)